# Set Docker attach option --sig-proxy=false to default

Tags: docker

I'm using docker v1.12.3. I know that by default `docker attach` option `--sig-proxy=true` but i'm wondering is it possible to change by default to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't.
this link explains how to set some options.
https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-set-the-docker-daemon-options 
But there is no way to set the --sig-proxy=false now, the options change between versions

--sig-proxy=true will not redirect received signals to the process.
So for example if you are attached to a container and press Ctrl+C, it would not impact in the process of the container, it would impact just in your console.

Example of use:

```
docker attach --sig-proxy=false <your_container_name>
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question.